# Week number of a quarter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get the week number of a given quarter based on the date.
I currently have this formula

```
=1+(WEEKNUM(EDATE(Y4,-1)))-(WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(EDATE(Y4,-1)), 
LOOKUP(MONTH(EDATE(Y4,-1)),{1,4,7,10}),1)))
```

But for *January*, it should be giving me 1 but it's giving me 10. Any suggestions?

Comment: when you choose a date in January, it's going back to December. 12 in your lookup array gives 10 as the result.  Perhaps instead of `EDATE`, you should use `EOMONTH(Y4,-1)+1`, so you look at the 1st of the current month for your calculation

Comment: When I tried that I get "chose a number greater or equal to 0 when evaluating eomonth.

Comment: I posted an answer but, really, I'm guessing - you should provide some specific examples - you say "January", surely you aren't expecting the same week number for the whole of January?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you expect this to work at the start and end of the quarter? Default `WEEKNUM` function starts week 1 on the 1st of January every year and week 2 starts on the next Sunday after 1st January.

Assuming your **quarter** week numbers should work the same way, i.e. week 1 starts on the 1st of Jan/Apr/Jul/Oct and week 2 starts on the next Sunday then that's actually equivalent to counting Sundays since 6 days back into the previous quarter.

You can do that using `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` function, i.e. with this formula:

`=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(EOMONTH(Y4,MOD(1-MONTH(Y4),-3)-1)-5,Y4,"1111110")`

format result as number with no decimal places

`NETWORKDAYS.INTL` function is available in `Excel 2010` and later versions - for older versions of Excel you can get the same results with this formula:

`=INT((13-WEEKDAY(Y4)+Y4-EOMONTH(Y4,MOD(1-MONTH(Y4),-3)-1))/7)`

Comment: I was guessing too when I posted the answer, but based my answer on actual week numbers dividing it by 13 and on the assumption that that week 53 is week 1 too. Nonetheless, you beat me on the guessing :)

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this in R but having trouble... Any suggestions? @L42

Comment: @AlexS.Sandoval Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=CHOOSE((MOD(WEEKNUM(Y4),13)=0)+1,WEEKNUM(Y4)-(ROUNDDOWN(WEEKNUM(Y4)/13,0)*13),13)
```

This will get the week number of a given date within a quarter.
I used this in one of my applications so you might be able to use it too. HTH.

<sub>**Note:** If you use 1st day other than *Sunday*, then adjust the `WEEKNUM` formula.</sub>

Comment: This worked nicely for me. I replaced the cell ref with the today() function. Very handy!

Answer (score 1):

(Expanded from comment)
when you choose a date in January, it's going back to December. 12 in your lookup array gives 10 as the result. Perhaps instead of EDATE, you should use EOMONTH(Y4,-1)+1, so you look at the 1st of the current month for your calculation

```
=1+(WEEKNUM(EOMONTH(Y4,-1)+1))-(WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(EOMONTH(Y4,-1)+1), LOOKUP(MONTH(EOMONTH(Y4,-1)+1),{1,4,7,10}),1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly interesting, since it changes with the year, and changes with what day of the week is the "start" of the week. So if a quarter starts on Saturday, and the week starts on a Saturday, the entire week is week 1. However, if it starts on a Sunday, week 1 is only one day long, and week 2 starts on Sunday.

The first question we have is, what day is it?

`=DayCheck`

Additionally, I'm going to call the start of each quarter the following:

```
Q1Start  = Date(Year(DayCheck),1,1)
Q2Start  = Date(Year(DayCheck),4,1)
Q3Start  = Date(Year(DayCheck),7,1)
Q4Start  = Date(Year(DayCheck),10,1)
```

The next question is, what's the first day of the week? We have some control over this with the Weekday function. For the sake of keeping it simple, Sunday is the start of the week.

Ok, that's our day. Next, what quarter is it?

```
`Quarter=ROUNDDOWN(MONTH(O16)/4,0)+1`
```

This gives us 1 for Q1, 2 for Q2, etc.

What day of the week is it now?

```
=WEEKDAY(DayCheck,1)
```

Ok, and now, what week are we on?

`=WEEKNUM(DayCheck,1)`

I'm going to put it together in a not very elegant fashion. I'm sure there's a better way out there.

```
=(Quarter=1)*((Weeknum(DayCheck)-WeekNum(Q1Start)+1)+(Quarter=2)*((Weeknum(DayCheck)-WeekNum(Q2Start)+1)+(Quarter=3)*((Weeknum(DayCheck)-WeekNum(Q3Start)+1)+(Quarter=4)*((Weeknum(DayCheck)-WeekNum(Q4Start)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try this as I got this as combination of 2 formula
=WEEKNUM(A1,1)-(INT((MONTH(A1)-1)/3)*13)

1. second part -  INT((MONTH(A1)-1)/3) gives us the quarter number of previous quarter which then multiplied with 13 weeks/quarter gives us how many weeks have passed in all previous quarter before current quarter.
2. First part - "WEEKNUM(A1,1)" gives us the week number of current week in the year.

so by deducting all the previous weeks in previous quarters from current week number of year, we get the current week number in current quarter.