# R: Get Week Number of a Quarter

Tags: r

I want to get the week number of a quarter in R. 
Week number begins on the first of the month and the next week starts on Sunday.

```
Date      WeekNum
1/1/2019  1
1/7/2019  2
2/7/2019  6
4/22/2019 4
5/1/2019  5
10/1/2019 1
```

In the past I've done it in excel, thanks to [Week number of a quarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983714/week-number-of-a-quarter)
but now I want to try this in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zoo` package would probably be most helpful for you.

```
library(zoo)
(as.integer(test$Date - as.Date(as.yearqtr(test$Date))) + match(weekdays(test$Date), weekdays(as.Date(3:9))) - 1L) %/% 7L + 1L
```

Comment: I found some errors when I ran this code for these dates. `df2 <- tibble(t_id = c(1:11),
              date = c("2014-09-01", "2019-01-18", "2019-02-01", "2016-11-21", "2017-10-05", "2018-03-31", "2015-08-31", "2014-06-20", "2020-01-31", "2017-08-08", "2019-01-01"))
df2$date <- as.Date(df2$date)
df2$WeekNum<- (as.integer(df2$date - as.Date(as.yearqtr(df2$date))) + match(weekdays(df2$date), weekdays(as.Date(3:9))) - 1L) %/% 7L + 1L
`

Comment: True #s should be `df2 <- tibble(t_id = c(1:11),
              date = c("2014-09-01", "2019-01-18", "2019-02-01", "2016-11-21", "2017-10-05", "2018-03-31", "2015-08-31", "2014-06-20", "2020-01-31", "2017-08-08", "2019-01-01"),
T2 = c(10,3,5,9,1,13,10,12,5,7,1))` Not sure why the first code gets them wrong.